# i am having trouble making this code work, i get the error 'TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list'

Tags: python

```
from keepalive import keep_alive
import discord
import os
import random 


client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
```

this part is probably also wrong..

```
greetings = ['hello','hey','hi','sup','wassup']
greetingresponse = ['good day mlady','hello miss/mr','greetings','good morning/afternoon','ahoy!']

greetingnumber = random.randint(0,4)
```

this part makes sure it doesnt reply to itself..

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

so this next part is the problem im pretty sure..

```
    if (greetings) in message.content.lower():
       await message.channel.send(greetingresponse)[greetingnumber]
```

Comment: As the error says, `greetings` must be a list (assuming `if (greetings) in message.content.lower():` is causing the error), and `list in string` doesn't make sense. What's your intent there? Do you mean `if message.content.lower() in greetings:`?

Comment: so this is a bot for discord, im trying to get it to identify certain messages from the greetings list, have it generate a random number and it would reply with something from the second list, with the random number determing which message it would send, if that makes sense?

Comment: im now getting the error : TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the possible greetings and check them one by one:

```
for greeting in greetings:
    if greeting in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send(greetingresponse[greetingnumber])
```

However this will always respond with the same greeting, chosen randomly when the bot starts. If you want it to be chosen randomly each time, place the line  `greetingnumber = random.randint(0,4)` just before `await message.channel.send(greetingresponse[greetingnumber])`.

Also, I assumed you want to answer whenever the message *contains* a greeting. If you want to answer when a message matches a greeting change the `in` to `==` in the `if` statement above.